# bootstrap tooltip from ajax request multiple line

Tags: ajax, tooltip

I have an ajax request and the result shound go in a bootstrap tooltip field.

´´´
function loadTooltip(idExecution) {

```
$('#tooltip' + idExecution).attr('title', "");

$.ajax({
    url: (URL + "managementExecution/getAllPartecipantsExecution/"),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        idExecution: idExecution
    },
    success: function (text) {
        $('body').tooltip({
            selector: '[rel=tooltip]'
        });

        $.each(text, function (k, v) {
            var oldTitle = "";
            var lastname = v.lastname;

            var oldTitle = $('#tooltip' + idExecution).attr('title');

            $('#tooltip' + idExecution).tooltip({html:true}).attr('title', oldTitle + "<br>" + lastname); 
        });
    }
});
```

}

This is my html:

```
 <a id="tooltip<?php echo $e['id'];?>" onmouseover="loadTooltip('<?php echo $e['id'];?>')" href="<?php echo URL . 'managementExecution/getDataExecution/' . $e[DB_EXECUTION_ID]; ?>">
                                        <?php echo date("d.m.y", strtotime($e[DB_EXECUTION_START]))."<br>".date("d.m.y", strtotime($e[DB_EXECUTION_END])); ?>
                                    </a>
```

It's working but the text is not going to a new line, the `<br>` tag is not recognized and i have the text with `<br>` inside

Comment: Hi, try like this : `$('#tooltip' + idExecution).tooltip({ html: true
    }).attr('data-original-title', oldTitle + "<br>" + lastname);` see if that works .

Comment: it works!! Thank you